# Blank CSV in splunk report

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

in splunk report, can we get at least header(column name)in attached CSV in autogenerated email, if there are no data in CSV/splunk..
eg. if no data then also it should atleast show header name..

Answer (score 0):

If there are no results, you shouldn't be getting anything sent to you in your Alert/Scheduled Report

Why would you expect to see header rows, when they only "exist" if there are rows of *data*?

When you run the Report manually, you'll note when there are "no results" there are, well ... "no results"

There is no header information because there is no information

#### Edit to address comment "there is one requirement from client that they want atleast column name if report is blank"

You need to *manually* create a "blank" report, then: something similar to this should work:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp 
| fillnull value="-" fieldA, fieldB, fieldC ...
<rest of search before stats>
| stats count by *
<rest of search>
```

That *should* mean when you eventually `stats`out your table, you'll have *at least* ***something*** "in every field" - which means you should always get at least one row (even if it's all dashes)

Comment: thanks @warren .. but there is one requirement from client that they want atleast column name if report is blank ..